# Como puedo hacer para que un JTabbedPane me devuelva el Panel que esta seleccionado?

Tags: java

mi problema es simple y complicado a la vez, ya que no se como podria hacer eso, pero estoy buscando que un JtabbedPane me devuelva el panel que esta seleccionado actualmente.

```
 private void botonCrearEscenasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    StringBuilder nombre_de_pestaña = new StringBuilder("Escena Nro " + this.cantidad_de_pestañas);
    Escena nueva_pestaña = new Escena();
    Panel nuevo_panel = new Panel(nueva_pestaña);
    this.paneles.add(String.valueOf(nombre_de_pestaña),nuevo_panel);
}
```

ese codigo solo añadiria un panel a jtabbed, y lo que quiero lograr es que me devuelva el tab seleccionado en el siguiente metodo

```
 private void crearCuadrado() {
    logger.debug("se verifica que el tamaño este en numeros");
    if (this.textoTamaño.getText().matches("\\d+")) {
        int tamaño = Integer.parseInt(this.textoTamaño.getText());
        if (tamaño <= 600) {
            logger.debug("Se da un nuevo tamaño,se crea el cuadrado");
            Cuadrado c = new Cuadrado(200, 50, tamaño);
            c.addListener("**QUE DEBERIA PONER AQUI PARA QUE ME DEVUELVA EL PANEL**");
            modelo.addFigura("**AQUI LO MISMO, ME DEVUELVA EL PANEL Y DEL PANEL SAQUE OTRO VALOR**");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "solo se aceptan tamaños menor/iguales a 600");
            logger.debug("solo se aceptan tamaños menor/iguales a 600");
            return;
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Solo se admiten numeros");
        logger.error("en esta seccion se da la condicion de solo usar numeros por lo cual el metodo se cierra ");
        return;
    }

}
```

el programa es un tipo de paint, que crea cuadrados y demas, el problema es solo eso, necesito una manera de que me devuelva el panel que este seleccionado en el Jtabbedpane

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: si.. aun me cuesta un poco explicar bien, pero logre resorverlo despues de un tiempo, para ser simple y tratar de explicarlo lo mejor posible, necesitaba que un JtabbedPane me devuelva el componente que le añadi, para ser exacto el componente que estaba seleccionado, la solucion la pondre como una autorespuesta ahurita

Answer (score 0):

Despues de un tiempo y varias paginas que explicaban los metodos que incluye el JtabbedPane encontre que al utilizar el metodo getSelectedComponent() devuelve el componente seleccionado

```
private void botonCrearEscenasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    StringBuilder nombre_de_pestaña;
    if(checkPordefecto.isSelected()){
        nombre_de_pestaña = new StringBuilder("Escena nro " + (paneles.getTabCount()+1));
    }else{
        nombre_de_pestaña = new StringBuilder(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Escriba el nombre de la Escena"));
    }

    Escena nueva_pestaña = new Escena();
    logger.debug("se crea una escena");
    Panel nuevo_panel = new Panel(nueva_pestaña);
    logger.debug("se añade a un panel");
    nuevo_panel.setNumero_de_panel((paneles.getTabCount()+1));
    this.paneles.add(String.valueOf(nombre_de_pestaña),nuevo_panel);
}
private void botonBorrarEscenaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    if(this.paneles.getSelectedComponent()==null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No hay escenas Seleccionadas o Disponibles");
        logger.debug("no hay escenas creadas");
        return;
    }
    this.panel = (Panel) this.paneles.getSelectedComponent();
    this.modelo = panel.getModelo();
    paneles.remove(paneles.getSelectedComponent());
    logger.debug("Se elimina el panel Numero "+ panel.getNumero_de_panel());
}
```

lo que hago es crear un panel que lleva dentro una clase Escena que maneja imagenes y figuras dentro del metodo crearEscenas, luego lo añado a mi JtabbedPane Que se llama **Paneles**, para que me devuelva el panel que esta seleccionado solo hago 2 variables aparte que me guarde el panel y la escena del panel seleccionado con el siguiente metodo

```
this.panel = (Panel) this.paneles.getSelectedComponent();
    this.modelo = panel.getModelo();
```

en resumen, jtabbedpane.getSelectedComponent() te devuelve el componente actualmente seleccionado, en mi caso lo guardo en un panel solo porque necesito el panel.